# Bootstrap with Webpack Encore functions with the internal webserver of Symfony 4 but not with LAMP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony4

I use Webpack Encore with a Symfony 4 project. Bootstrap functions if I run **php bin/console server:run** and I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000

But, when I launch Apache in order to use the link http://localhost/show-my-pictures/public/index.php Bootstrap stop functioning. And the console developper gives me:

```
The script from “http://localhost/build/runtime.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
```

I don't understand what is happening. Can you help me please?

**Webpack.config.js**

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin'); // this line tell to webpack to use the plugin

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if you JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())

    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    .autoProvidejQuery()

    .addPlugin(new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: './assets/images', to: 'images' }
    ]))
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Comment: Could you post your `webpack config` file?

Answer (score 0):

Your public path is not the right one when running your app in Apache, which causes assets not to be loaded properly.

Since you have a subdirectory in this case (`show-my-pictures`) you should take it into account when calling `Encore.setPublicPath()`:

```js
Encore.setPublicPath('/show-my-pictures/build')
```

See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/faq.html#my-app-lives-under-a-subdirectory

Comment: I followed what you told but it did not function. **yarn encore dev** does not function anymore. It functions only with Encore.setPublicPath('/build'). The build folder is under public. show-my-picture is the folder of the project.

Comment: What do you mean by "yarn encore dev does not function anymore"?

Comment: **yarn encore dev** allows to generate the css and the js files. And with **Encore.setPublicPath('/show-my-pictures/build')**, it does not function anymore and I have this: `Error: Cannot determine how to prefix the keys in manifest.json. Call Encore.setManifestKeyP  refix() to choose what path (e.g. build/) to use when building your manifest keys. This is c  aused by setOutputPath() (/srv/http/show-my-pictures/public/build) and setPublicPath() (/sho  w-my-pictures/build) containing paths that don't seem compatible.`

Comment: You have the description of what you need to do in the error message: "Call Encore.setManifestKeyPrefix() to choose what path (e.g. build/) to use when building your manifest keys.". It's also present in the documentation I linked in my answer just above.


In your case it should work with `Encore.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')`.


Note that with this config the paths will only be right with Apache.

Comment: You need to be more specific when you say things like "it does not function". What does it do now? Do you still have an error? If yes, is that the same error?

Comment: I don't have error when I launch **yarn encore dev** but there is no image and bootstrap is not activated when I browse on http://localhost/show-my-pictures/public/.